# Find all elements with data-attr with jquery

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

**Objective:**

Find all elements with the data-attribute **parent-cat-number == my_cat_number**.

As you can see from the markup I get the parent-category integer from the atribute "data-cat-number", but I fail at finding all the children with that as their parent-cat-number.

Here's an example of how it could look http://jsfiddle.net/jahrichie/jGpcx/ , but right now the click of a parent shows all children. I'd like to adapt it to only show the children of that element.

**JS http://jsfiddle.net/jahrichie/jGpcx/**

```
    $('.parent-category').click(function () {
        var my_cat_number = $(this).attr('data-cat-number');
        $(this).children().find("[parent-cat-number] = my_cat_number").show();

    })
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="category-faceted">
    <div class="parent-category" data-cat-number="1">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Celebrity</a>
        <div class="child-category" parent-cat-number="1">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">Sub-Celebrity</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent-category" data-cat-number="2">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Entertainment</a>
        <div class="child-category" parent-cat-number="2">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">Sub-Ent</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this [**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jGpcx/5/)

```
$('.parent-category').on('click', function () {
  var my_cat_number = $(this).data('cat-number');
  $(this).find('*').each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('parent-cat-number') == my_cat_number)
      $(this).show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$(this).children().find("[parent-cat-number] = '" + my_cat_number + "'").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.parent-category').on('click', function () {
    var my_cat_number = $(this).data('cat-number');

    $('*', this).filter(function() {
        return $(this).attr('parent-cat-number') == my_cat_number;
    }).show();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jGpcx/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as:

```
$('.parent-category a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent()
        .find('[parent-cat-number="'+$(this).parent().data('cat-number')+'"]')
        .show();
    return false;
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jGpcx/4/)**